# Attempting to assign values to TextBoxes in code behind in ListView in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, textbox

I'm attempting to insert a value into TextBoxes in a ListView according to the user id label value of the student in the ListView. In the front end there is a textbox for each student listed to type in a grade for. Below is part of my code I have written to attempt to find the TextBox Control, retrieve results that are already there and assign to the TextBoxes matching the correct student:

```
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row moduleDrop">

            <h2>Final module results</h2>
            <h4>Select the degree programme:</h4>
            <asp:Label ID="degreeProgValue" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="degreeSelect" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UniString %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT pathway_years.id, (pathway_year + ' ' + pathway ) AS pathwayDetails FROM pathways INNER JOIN pathway_years ON pathways.id = pathway_years.pathway_id"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="degreeProgDropDown" runat="server" Width="420" AutoPostBack="true"
                DataSourceID="degreeSelect" DataTextField="pathwayDetails" DataValueField="id">
            </asp:DropDownList>


        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row moduleDrop">
            <h4>Select module:</h4>
            <asp:Label ID="TBTest" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:Label>
            <br />

            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="modSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UniString %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT module_on_pathway.module_id, modules.module_name FROM modules INNER JOIN module_on_pathway ON modules.id = module_on_pathway.module_id INNER JOIN pathway_years ON module_on_pathway.pathway_year_id = pathway_years.id INNER JOIN class ON pathway_years.id = class.pathway_year_id INNER JOIN classlist ON class.class_id = classlist.class_id INNER JOIN users ON classlist.user_id = users.id WHERE mandatory_module = 1 AND pathway_years.id = @pwayYearid UNION SELECT module_on_pathway.id, modules.module_name FROM modules INNER JOIN module_on_pathway ON modules.id = module_on_pathway.module_id INNER JOIN pathway_years ON module_on_pathway.pathway_year_id = pathway_years.id INNER JOIN class ON pathway_years.id = class.pathway_year_id INNER JOIN classlist ON class.class_id = classlist.class_id INNER JOIN chosen_modules_list ON classlist.classlist_id = chosen_modules_list.classlist_id INNER JOIN users ON classlist.user_id = users.id WHERE chosen_modules_list.module_on_pathway_id = module_on_pathway.id AND pathway_years.id = @pwayYearid">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="degreeProgDropDown" Name="pwayYearid" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="modDropDown" runat="server" Width="420" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true"
                DataSourceID="modSource" DataTextField="module_name" DataValueField="module_id">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <br />
    </div>

    <div class="classList">

        <h4>Select the student:</h4>
        <br />
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQLStudentList" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UniString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT  students_profile.user_id,  first_name, last_name FROM classlist
        INNER JOIN students_profile ON classlist.user_id = students_profile.user_id
        INNER JOIN class ON classlist.class_id = class.class_id
        INNER JOIN pathway_years ON class.pathway_year_id = @pwayYearid
        INNER JOIN module_on_pathway ON pathway_years.id = module_on_pathway.pathway_year_id
        WHERE module_on_pathway.mandatory_module = 1
        AND  module_on_pathway.module_id = @modpwayid

        UNION
        SELECT  students_profile.user_id, first_name, last_name FROM classlist
        INNER JOIN students_profile ON classlist.user_id = students_profile.user_id
        INNER JOIN class ON classlist.class_id = class.class_id
        INNER JOIN pathway_years ON class.pathway_year_id =  @pwayYearid
        INNER JOIN module_on_pathway ON pathway_years.id = module_on_pathway.pathway_year_id
        INNER JOIN chosen_modules_list ON classlist.classlist_id = chosen_modules_list.classlist_id
        WHERE chosen_modules_list.module_on_pathway_id = module_on_pathway.id 
        AND  module_on_pathway.module_id = @modpwayid">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="degreeProgDropDown" Name="pwayYearid" />
                <asp:ControlParameter Name="modpwayid" ControlID="modDropDown" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:ListView runat="server" OnItemDataBound="studentsListView_ItemDataBound" ID="studentsListView" DataSourceID="SQLStudentList">
            <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <strong><span style="">Student Number:</strong>
                <asp:Label ID="user_idLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("user_id") %>' />
                <br />
                <strong>Name:</strong>
                <asp:Label ID="first_nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("first_name") %>' />
                <asp:Label ID="last_nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("last_name") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="finalMarkAssignment" runat="server" Width="40"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label ID="gradeForStudent" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-success" ID="submitModuleMark" OnClientClick="ShowLabel();" runat="server" Text="Submit Grade" OnClick="submitModuleMark_Click" />
                <br />

                <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-success" ID="repeatSubmitModuleMark" OnClientClick="ShowLabel();" runat="server" Text="Submit repeat module grade" OnClick="repeatSubmitModuleMark_Click" />
                <br />
                <br />
                </span>
            </AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <span style="">user_id:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="user_idTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("user_id") %>' />
                    <br />
                    first_name:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="first_nameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("first_name") %>' />
                    <br />
                    last_name:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="last_nameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("last_name") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                    <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </span>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <span>No data was returned.</span>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <span style="">user_id:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="user_idTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("user_id") %>' />
                    <br />
                    first_name:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="first_nameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("first_name") %>' />
                    <br />
                    last_name:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="last_nameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("last_name") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                    <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </span>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <span style="">
                    <strong>Student Number:</strong>
                    <asp:Label ID="user_idLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("user_id") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <strong>Name:</strong>
                    <asp:Label ID="first_nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("first_name") %>' />
                    <asp:Label ID="last_nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("last_name") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="finalMarkAssignment" runat="server" Width="40"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-success" ID="submitModuleMark" OnClientClick="ShowLabel();" runat="server" Text="Submit Grade" OnClick="submitModuleMark_Click" />
                    <br />

                    <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-success" ID="repeatSubmitModuleMark" OnClientClick="ShowLabel();" runat="server" Text="Submit repeat module grade" OnClick="repeatSubmitModuleMark_Click" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </span>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <div id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" style="">
                    <span runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
                </div>
                <div style="">
                </div>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <SelectedItemTemplate>
                <span style="">user_id:
                    <asp:Label ID="user_idLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("user_id") %>' />
                    <br />
                    first_name:
                    <asp:Label ID="first_nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("first_name") %>' />
                    <br />
                    last_name:
                    <asp:Label ID="last_nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("last_name") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </span>
            </SelectedItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>


    </div>


    <div class="col-sm-12">

        <br />

        <asp:Label ID="changedFlag" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="assignmentIDValue" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="pOrF" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="EnterFinalMark" runat="server" Visible="false">Enter a final mark for this module</asp:Label>
        <br />


        <asp:Label ID="success" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="Grade has been changed successfully"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="changedVAL" Visible="false" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do not concatenate strings for your queries. Used parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

When you put a breakpoint on `TextBox TB` does it have a value when you step into it?

I suspect that you haven't put this code within a method that fires on data binding for the listview items, and you need to. If you put it elsewhere (eg on page load), it won't be able to find the individual text boxes.

First you need to subscribe to the ItemDataBound event of the ListView in your page load code. You can either do this declaratively in your front-end code

```
<asp:ListView ID="studentsListView" OnItemDataBound="listView_OnItemDataBound" runat="server"></asp:ListView>
```

Or you can do it in the page load in the back end code

```
studentsListView.ItemDataBound += listView_OnItemDataBound();
```

And then for each item, you can do something with it

```
protected void listView_OnItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
   // get the button or any other control on the current row
   TextBox tB = (TextBox) e.Item.FindControl("finalMarkAssignment");
   if(tb != null)
  {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: what would ideally be the method to have this code in? I'm a novice with issues like this.

Comment: I've my code in an OnItemDataBound event now but still no luck. I'll update my question with the code I have now

Comment: Is TB null or does it have a value when you put a breakpoint on it? Also, if you're going to post your edits, I highly recommend removing any extraneous code that is not directly related to your problem, it makes it difficult to see the problem that you are having

Comment: yeah, all that sql code and whatnot in there is not relevant to your problem. You are not getting a reference to the text box, and that's the issue. Please post your aspx (relevant section). I assume since you say TB is null that you are able to actually step into the listView_OnItemDataBound method, yes?

Comment: I've posted the aspx now

Comment: I've also discovered that when debugging it returns the label as null too. I've added a for loop in the code behind to find each label and textbox in the ListView but this hasn't worked. Do you know of any way I could fix this?

Comment: Hi Spiros, you've changed your posted code to something completely different than what you had before. The code behind is now gone. And the code that you posted has all kinds of extra, unrelated stuff in it. You're not going to get much help if you post up a wall of text and expect people to dig through it; you have to create a sample with your specific problem, show what you've tried, and what problem you're having and go from there. I suggest you create a new question with a much narrower problem.